# jsmvc stealjs process issue

Tags: javascriptmvc

When using the buildjs to generate production javascript for jsmvc module, the command process exits without any information, this behavior is sporadic, some times (without any changes) it generates production javascript, the observation we made is CPU process is spiking to 100% and exits after few seconds.

I trying to know are there any body who faced similar process issues while running buildjs, or is there any minimum processor configuration needed to run buildjs. Any help appreciated.

js .\steal\buildjs modulename\xyz.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after further debugging we found the issue with lesser CPU configuration is because of setTimeOut call in env.js, when replaced the setTimeOut call with setInterval it worked fine. We haven't debugged further why it broke in setTimeOut of env.js but as of now this solution works.